# Вызывающая и вызываемая функции, правильный способ выделения и очистки памяти

Tags: c++

Есть следующий код и вопрос: "Как делать правильно?"
Приведены два класса и main(). Выполняемая работа и проблема описана ниже.

```
class Getter
{
private:
    Buffer buffer_; // тип Buffer - или vector<char>, или std::string
public:
    //...
};

void Getter::getPacket(const char* message, size_t size)
{
    //...
    // Как-то обрабатываем пакет, по мере работы с пакетом сохраняем переработанный пакет в buffer_

    // Варианты отправки пакета:
    // 1) 
    sendPacket(buffer_.c_str(), buffer_.size()) // или то же самое sendPacket(buffer_.data(), buffer_.size())
    // Минусы: не знаем как обрабатывается пакет в Sender::sendPacket, 
    // не знаем копируются ли там данные, можем перезаписать данные в buffer_ к моменту, когда в Sender::sendPacket начнется работа с предыдущими
    // Но и не нужно чистить память.

     // 2) Выделяем память в куче при помощи new []
     char* data = new char[newSize];
     memcpy(data, buffer_.data(), newSize);
     sendPacket(data, newSize);
     // Вопрос: кто должен чистить память?

     //...
}

class Sender
{
private:
    vector<string> packets_;
public:
    //...
}

void Sender::sendPacket(const char* message, size_t size)
{
    // Возможная работа с данными, которая нас устроила бы

    // 1) 
    packets_.emplace_back(message, size);
    // 2) 
    packets_.emplace_back(message, size);
    delete [] message;

    // Возможная работа с данными, которая нас не устраивает

    // 1)
    vector<pair<const char*, size_t> packets;
    packets.emplace(message, size);

    // 2) Не вызов delete []
}

int main()
{
    Sender sender;
    Getter getter(&sender);

    while (true)
    {
        const char* data = GetDataFromDevice();
        size_t size = GetSizeFromDevice();

        // какое-нибудь условие для выхода

        getter.getPacket(data, size);
    }
}
```

Comment: почему не использовать string везде, раз вы, насколько видно из приведённого кода, нигде не работаете с массивом символов

Comment: Просто есть интерфейсы ISender и IGetter, в которых описаны методы именно с такими сигнатурами.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Память должна освобождаться на том уровне, где она была выделена. Допустимое исключение когда вызываемая функция выделяет память и возвращает ее. Но тогда в документации к этой функции должно быть четко указано как эту память освобождать.

Вызываемая функция **никогда** не должна освобождать переданную память. Просто потому, что она не знает каким образом память была выделена. Если функции нужны переданные данные после завершения своей работы, она должна скопировать эти данные в свой буфер

Comment: Спасибо, такой ответ мне был и нужен.